# Drops from hoppers are not going into the nearby chest

Tags: xbox-one, minecraft-legacy-console

In Minecraft on the Xbox One, the drops from the hoppers are not going into the nearby chest. How do you connect them?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Could you give us some more detail, such as version number, block setup, and/or screenshots?

Answer (score 3):

The chest cannot just be "nearby" the hopper output must be right on the chest.

From the wiki:

> To place a hopper, use the Place Block control while aiming at the surface to which its output should face (a hopper will not automatically orient itself to point at a container). To place a hopper so that it faces a container (or other block which has a Use Item interaction), sneak while placing the hopper. A hopper placed while aiming at the bottom of a block will re-orient to face down instead. Hoppers won't change their direction after being placed and aren't "attached" to the container they are facing -- the container can be removed and the hopper will continue to face in the same direction.